# Receiving 500 internal error from Pay Pal Rest API

Tags: php, paypal

Just started using the pay pal REST API and am trying to process an authorization with a test credit card. I have done what should be most of the debugging (correct credit card credentials, exp dates etc) up to the point of what seems like it should be a successful authorization, except no matter what i try it always responds with 500 internal error. This is for a sandbox test on an application. Is this is a paypal issue or an issue with what i am submitting?

response:

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 Content-Type: application/json Content-Length: 145 Date: Sat, 17 Aug 2013 02:28:28 GMT Connection: close
>   {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","information_link":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"abaf402d9997f"}

** Update **
it was due to using the credit card 4111111111111111. once substituted with 4417119669820331 it works fine